# Javascript onkeypress interferes with rest of page

Tags: javascript, html

On a site where some calculated answers must be given, I have implemented an invisible-until-button-clicked `<div>` with a simple calculator. I want to be able to operate this calculator using the physical keyboard.

I can use `document.onkeypress= function(key){ reactKey(key); }`, and I can catch the keys pressed. However, the div-buttons I use in my form no longer work, which also means I cannot even summon the hidden div with the calculator.

I have tried to associate the onkeypress with the calculator div, but then the key presses go undetected.

Ideally, I want the key press to be detected and used in a conditional function:

```
document.onkeyup= function(key){ reactKey(key); }

function reactKey(evt) {
    isVisible = document.getElementById("calcRow").style.display;
    if (isVisible=="table-row") {
            // use key for calculator function
        }
    } else {
        //go about business as usual
    }
}
```

Neither `return true;` not `return false` seem to do this.

Anybody any ideas?

Please note I am trying to avoid using JQuery, as it seems silly to link in an entire library for only this functionality.

Comment: Have you logged your isVisible variable? Since you are saving display values in that variable, it should give you values like 'none', 'inline' etc. And you are comparing it with "table-row" which will become false.

Comment: there is syntax error, before `else`, you are putting one more `}`, remove that and try.

Comment: To add to @RahulJain information, enable your browsers "developer tools" so that you can see when errors occur, to help debug these matters.

Comment: I have checked; when the div is visible, the isVisible is 'table-row'.

Comment: The syntax error is only here, because I wrote code without checking. It is correct in source.

Comment: Are you using `iframe`s and all? Did you try adding breakpoints in these functions? The code and information you are giving here is not sufficient to find out what exactly the problem is. Could you provide jsfiddle link?